# IAE: Service not registered on unbindService after Service.stopSelf

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm binding to an android Service as demonstrated in the [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample)

```
private boolean bound = false;
private MyService service = null;

private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service connected");
        service = (MyService) service;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service disconnected");
        service = null;
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    if (bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT)) {
        bound = true;
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Service bind failed");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (bound) {
        unbindService(connection);
        bound = false;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Sometimes, the Service stops itself calling `stopSelf` or is stopped by `stopService`, resulting in all clients being unbound. But the variable `bound` here is still true, so `onPause` will throw the following Exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: de.ncoder.sensorsystem.android.app.MainActivity$1@359da29
            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1022)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1802)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:550)
            at de.ncoder.sensorsystem.android.app.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:121)
            at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6044)
            ...
```

Is there a simple way to check if a Service is still bound and alive?
As far as I know, [`onServiceDisconnected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected(android.content.ComponentName)) will leave bindings active (as it is only called under extreme circumstances, where the Service is hopefully being restarted soon), so setting `bound` to false there won't help.

Answer (score 2):

In the most situations you would like to have service running while an activity is bind to it. The solutions for this case - add flag BIND_AUTO_CREATE to service binding call and service will run until you call unbind even if stopService or stopSelf were called.

Otherwise, as far as I know,  the only option is to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `stopSelf()` in your service then your `onSerivceDisconnected()` will get called

So change `bound` value to `false` in `onSerivceDisconnected()` of your `Activity`

```
 @Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service disconnected");
    bound=false;
    service = null;
}
```

Comment: But the JavaDoc for onServiceDisconnected states that it does not remove the ServiceConnection itself and the binding to the service will remain active

Comment: If I do not unbind the Service if it was previously stopped with `stopSelf`, I get an `ServiceConnectionLeaked` warning. `onServiceDisconnected` is only called if the Service was stopped via `stopSelf` and not via `stopService`.